# How to make an image appear in HTML given specific condition?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make an image appear when the value for a slider is at a given position. (This is for a pH meter, so I need a specific image for a given pH value) I am relatively new to HTML, here is what I've got so far. The fish image that has already been inserted is an image I would like to only appear when the pH value is 7. Thanks in advance.

```html
<html>
</p>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p style="color:#165D61;font-family:verdana;font-size:300%;text-align:center;">pH Level
</p>

<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="0" max="14" value="7" class="slider" id="myRange">
  <p style="color:#20C2CA;font-family:verdana;font-size:150%;"> Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
</div>


<p class="aligncenter">
    <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/adorable-clown-fish-with-water-bubbles-isolated-on-white-background-vector-id490358972?k=6&m=490358972&s=612x612&w=0&h=XxO-HGidvKMTVC9ZkHDhjTfgb1M0uabQRyQzjF6016s=" alt="centered image" style=";width:200px;height:250px;" />
</p>

<style>
.aligncenter {
    text-align: center;
}
</style>

<script>
if (demo == 7) {
<img src="happy_fish.jpg"
}
</script>

<script>
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the event inside the on change function then you can access the value with `e.target.value` :

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");

function changeValue(value) {
  output.innerHTML = value;
  document.getElementById('fish-image').style.display = value == 7 ? 'block' : 'none';
}
changeValue(slider.value); // To display or not the image when visiting the page (before changing the slider value)

slider.onchange = function(e) {
  changeValue(e.target.value);
}
```

```css
.slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.aligncenter {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<p style="color:#165D61;font-family:verdana;font-size:300%;text-align:center;">pH Level
</p>

<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="0" max="14" value="8" class="slider" id="myRange" />
  <p style="color:#20C2CA;font-family:verdana;font-size:150%;"> Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
</div>


<p class="aligncenter">
    <img id="fish-image" src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/adorable-clown-fish-with-water-bubbles-isolated-on-white-background-vector-id490358972?k=6&m=490358972&s=612x612&w=0&h=XxO-HGidvKMTVC9ZkHDhjTfgb1M0uabQRyQzjF6016s=" alt="centered image" style=";width:200px;height:250px;" />
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Create an id myImage in  <img/>  
 
var slider = document.getElementById('myRange');
var output = document.getElementById('demo');
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function () {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
  if (slider.value === '7') {
// The image will display if true
    document.getElementById('myImage').style.visibility = 'visible';
  } else {
//  The image will not display if false
    document.getElementById('myImage').style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
};
```